# KeyError in Django when trying to dynamically create a model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to dynamically create a table for a game when that game is created. This table will have details about users playing the game. I don't know how to create dynamic models,so am following this tutorial: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels. It may be old as my Django version is 1.7.1, I am not sure.

My relevant code samples are given below:

```
    def addgame(request):

...
name = request.POST.get('name','')
                #declare the field types in the table
                fields = { 'player' : models.ForeignKey(User),'registration_date' : models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False),
                        'highest_score' : models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True), 'most_recent_score' : models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
                    }
                #call create_gamemodel view to create the table for the game being added.
                model = create_gamemodel(name,fields)   

    ...


def create_gamemodel(name, fields=None, module=''):

    class Meta:
        # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model creation
        pass

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    return model
```

The error trace is given below:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mukhera3/Desktop/game_store/wsdProject/gamestore/views.py" in addgame
  146.          model = create_gamemodel(name,fields)   
File "/home/mukhera3/Desktop/game_store/wsdProject/gamestore/views.py" in create_gamemodel
  183.  model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __new__
  109.                 model_module = sys.modules[new_class.__module__]

Exception Type: KeyError at /addgame/
Exception Value: ''
```

Apparently there is something wrong with the lines:

```
model = create_gamemodel(name,fields) (in addgame(request) view)
model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs) (in create_gamemodel view)
```

I can't quite understand what the problem is, and am not sure if this is the right way to create dynamic models. Please help!

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic model? Why have separate games for each game at all? The fields don't change, seems like you just need a single model with an extra field for `game`.

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic table?  It would seem more logical to have, eg, a `Players` table, with a foreign key to the `Game` table, representing their current game.

Comment: Actually I am supposed to show some game statistics as well as store player scores for a game. So I have a 'master' Game table, which has static information like name of the game, who created it, it's price etc. I also have a transactional table for each game, which stores IDs of players who have registered for that game, date of registration, and scores.

Comment: @sapi I see what you mean, but a player can register for multiple games, and have separate scores for each game. Would that fit in the Players table?

Comment: You probably want something like a many to many relation between games and players (each game has many players, and each player has many scores). Alternatively, you could have a Score table with a foreign key to both Game and Player (such that each game has many scores, and each score belongs to a single player). It's hard to say what's best without a deeper understanding of your app, but dynamic tables should be very rare.

Comment: @sapi I did not think of that - a Scores table would solve many problems. The fields could be game ID, player ID, highest score, most recent score, and date of registration for that game. Thank you for the tip!!